# Second monitor doesn't work (DP & HDMI)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I'm trying to make two monitors works, but the secondary monitor always says it has **no signal**, no matter which one of the two I uses as the main.

Both are working perfectly by themselves. The main monitor (1920x1090) uses **Display Port** @144hz and the secondary (1440x900) uses **HDMI** @60hz.

My GPU is the **Zotac RTX 2060 Twin Fan**.

When I boot up the computer, both screen shows the boot screen. The "no signal" problem starts when loading **Windows 10 Pro**. This makes me thinks it's a software problem, but I might be wrong. I have no clue on what to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Pressed '<Windows>' and '<P>' keys to switch the display to the second monitor or extend across both displays? Do you see the extra display in your display settings? (Right click on desktop and select "Display settings", then scroll down to the "Multiple Displays" section) The monitor may well be working but you have not told Windows to *use* it.

Comment: Right click your desktop and click "Display settings". Make sure you have "Extend these displays" selected.

Comment: Only one monitor works, which is the main from the beginning. It doesn't extend nor change. If I start with the main monitor being the 60hz one, it will keep it that way and the 144hz will not work.

Comment: But do you see it in "display settings"? We get that it "will not work" but your question fails to tell us whether you have actually **enabled** it using the appropriate settings or whether it even appears to the operating system in the first place. Both Niall and myself told you where to go to give us information and to turn on both screens, if available.

Comment: Yes. Everything appears like it should be working but it doesn't. Sorry if I didn't made it clear.